# Ionic 3 Cannot find name 'google' on first load

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on Ionic 3 and when I try to load the google package, just on the first time to run the project, it fails because it does not find the name 'google'. I supose that the problem is I don't wait until the google Library is loaded, but I have no idea how could I solve this.
My code is the following:

```
displayTrafficLayer(){
   this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
     try{
       this.pageInfo.trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer(); 
       this.pageInfo.trafficLayer.setMap(this.mapInstance);
     }catch(e){
       console.warn('does not found google once is load for first time');
       return;
     }
   });
}
```

It crash when initialize the `new google.maps`.
How could I wait to load the google library? As I said, when I reload the page it works. Maybe some race condition?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share more code, please? What is `google` in this context and what is the actual error and stack trace?

Comment: `declare var google;` after your `imports` before class.